# How to display markdown frontmatter as HTML in Gatsby

Tags: html, graphql, markdown, gatsby, netlify-cms

my index-page displays blurbs with image and text.
But i cant get the text to be formated as HTML. Im using the markdown-widget with Netlify CMS and want linebreak to work when spacing content in the admin view.
ive tried use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={item.text}` aswell without any luck.

item is just a mapping of all blurbs.

```
<p> {item.text} </p>
```

graphql:

```
markdownRemark(frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "index-page" } }) {
      frontmatter {
        intro {
          blurbs {
            image {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 2048, quality: 100) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
            heading
            text
          }
          heading
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

the label in config.yml:

```
- {label: "Intro", name: "intro", widget: "object", fields: [{label: "Heading", name: "heading", widget: "string"}, {label: "Description", name: "description", widget: text}, {label: Blurbs, name: blurbs, widget: "list", fields: [{label: "Image", name: "image", widget: "image"}, {label: "Rubrik", name: "heading", widget: "string"}, {label: "Text", name: "text", widget: "markdown"}]}]}
```

the Index.md i want to read from (i guess this works, due to the fact that i get the data to display, just not in html form)

```
  blurbs:
    - image: /img/img1.jpg
      heading: heading one
      text: >-
        This is the content i want in HTML
    
    - image: /img/img2.jpg
      heading: heading two
      text: >-
        This is also the content i want in HTML
       
        And this should give me a linebreak
```

Answer (score 4):

You can acchieve this using the [gatsby-transformer-remark-frontmatter](https://github.com/WhiteAbeLincoln/gatsby-transformer-remark-frontmatter) plugin.

Install the plugin and add it to your gatsby-config.js:

```
$ npm install gatsby-transformer-remark-frontmatter
```

```js
// in your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  'gatsby-transformer-remark',
  'gatsby-transformer-remark-frontmatter'
]
```

To tell Gatsby that the text field within each blurb contains markdown and that you want the string to be transformed to html, you need to add a @md directive to your schema. To do that, add the following code to the `gatsby-node.js` file.

```js
// in your gatsby-node.js

exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const {createTypes} = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type MarkdownRemark implements Node {
      frontmatter: Frontmatter
    }

    type Frontmatter {
      intro: Intro
    }

    type Intro {
      blurbs: [Blurb]
    }

    type Blurb {
      text: String @md
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

Now the `text` field of the blurbs will have a special `html` field that you can include in your query:

```
markdownRemark(frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "index-page" } }) {
      frontmatter {
        intro {
          blurbs {
            text {
              html
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Lastly, in your component, you should be able to loop over the blurbs and render the html like so:

```js
...
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: blurb.text.html }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything's properly set, as it seems.

By default, there's a `html` property right inside `frontmatter`:

```
markdownRemark(frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "index-page" } }) {
      frontmatter {
        html
        intro {
          blurbs {
            image {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 2048, quality: 100) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                }
              }
            }
            heading
            text
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

*Note: test your query at `localhost:8000/___graphql`*

Once you have queried it, just display it as you did, nesting to the correct property:

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html}
```

You can check for a full tutorial at https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/sourcing-data/sourcing-from-netlify-cms/

Comment: The problem is that i dont have text data in the HTML section in the md file. As i understand it the HTML is the code after the ending  ===. 
 I want it in the text frontmatter key/value , but render as html. If that make sense?

Comment: In that case, inside the `frontmatter` there must be an item if your object. If you query it (in the `localhost:8000/___graphql`) it should display the HTML. That field, can be displayed using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Comment: The “blurbs” is an array of objects, but I can’t find a html in that nested level. Can only query image, heading and text 

Comment: Is the field set as markdown in the widget?

Comment: Yeah it is! Could it be some problem due to it being in a list widget?

Comment: It shouldn't. Have you tried the `mode` option? https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/widgets/#markdown

Comment: I use both raw and rich, so I have the toggle option in the cms

Comment: I added the lable from config.yml  and the index.md if anone sees the problem?

Comment: I make an example like yours and I'm able to display it. Once you query it (using the name of the markdown field, `text` in this case), you need to print it whatever you want. I use `markdown-to-jsx`library

Comment: I can display it, but i want the cms text formatting to be displayed as well.  E.g if I make the text in different sections I want row breaks. or if I make some word bold it should be that on the site to  (if that makes sense?